# Powershell: how to properly use ValueFromRemainingArguments?

Tags: powershell-5.0, positional-parameter

I'm following along the official Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7) in order to define one mandatory positional argument and any amount of remaining positional arguments that may follow by using `ValueFromRemainingArguments`.
My attempt:

```
function main {
    Param(
        [String]
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        $FOO,
        [String[]]
        [Parameter(Position = 1, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        $BAR
    )
    
    Write-Host mandatory arg: $FOO
    Write-Host additional args: $BAR

}

&main $args[0] $args
```

When I try to run the script, I get the following output:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\script.ps1 foo bar bar2 bar3
mandatory arg: foo
additional args: foo bar bar2 bar3
```

Expected output:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\script.ps1 foo bar bar2 bar3
mandatory arg: foo
additional args: bar bar2 bar3
```

How to produce the desired output?

If I separate args by comma:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\script.ps1 foo bar,bar2,bar3
```

the output is:

```
PS C:\ps_scripts> .\script.ps1 foo bar,bar2,bar3
mandatory arg: foo
additional args: foo System.Object[]
```

Comment: Args is an automatic variable that contains all arguments. So you’re literally calling main giving the first argument to foo and all arguments to bar.

Answer (score 0):

The last line should be modified like this:

```
&main $args[0] $args[1]
```